# Python turtle graphics no onkey attribute

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

What is wrong with this because I had it working a while ago...?

```
[CALCULATIONS ABOVE HERE]

projectile = turtle.Turtle()

# Default velocity speed
global velocity
velocity = 200

# Increase projectile velocity
def increase_velocity():
    up += 5
    velocity.up

# Decrease projectile velocity
def decrease_velocity():
    down -= 5
    velocity.down()

# Set key bindings    
projectile.onkey(increase_velocity, "Right")
projectile.onkey(decrease_velocity, "Left")
```

AttributeError: 'Turtle' object has no attribute 'onkey'

Comment: Also did I do my functions right? Will the global velocity be changed within both increase/decrease functions?

Comment: `onkey` is a function defined in `turtle` itself.  Use `turtle.onkey(...`

Comment: can you help me out with global/local variables because I can't get this working correctly.

Comment: Your best bet may be to review or take a tutorial or two.  For starters here, you've set `velocity` to an integer....then you're trying to access some attribute, `up` on that integer (which doesn't exist)...and you're trying to call some method `down()` on that same integer (which again doesn't exist).  You could also try to get answers on: [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Gerrat  [Code Review doesn't work with broken code](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/3649/my-question-was-closed-as-being-off-topic-what-are-my-options/3650#3650).  If he fixes the code, we could help.  Until then, this is a better place.

Answer (score 0):

Just solved this problem myself.

I do not understand the reasoning, but "projectile" does not inherit all methods from the turtle module, even though the projectile object inherits from the Turtle object.

When you set the keybindings for your object, use just "onkey," but you will have to call the method for the object in the function, forcing you to make your methods under a projectile class. For example:

```
turtle2 = Turtle()
def move_forward():
    turtle2.fd(50)
onkey(move_forward, "up")
```

It could also be an issue of using a global variable. You might want to make velocity a class variable.

```
class projectile(Turtle):
   velocity = 200

   def increase_velocity():
       up += 5
       velocity.up

   def decrease_velocity():
       down -= 5
       velocity.down()

onkey(projectile.increase_velocity, "Right")
onkey(projectile.decrease_velocity, "Left")
```

All i know is that the onkey method can only be called by the turtle module, and not by its classes.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Does your 'turtle2' really work? First, "up" rasies an error - it should be "Up". But even after correcting this, it simply doesn't work with me.